# Pandas convert column to multiple by groups

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I've got a situation where I've got two columns, where one is the category id and another is the category value. Since the values have different meanings for different categories, I want to extract the values to separate columns. So for example, I'd like to convert

```
+----+--------+
| id | value  |
+----+--------+
| 1  |      1 |
| 1  |      2 |
| 2  |      1 |
| 2  |      2 |
| 3  |      1 |
| 3  |      2 |
+----+--------+
```

to this:

```
+----+---------+---------+---------+
| id | value_1 | value_2 | value_3 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+
|  1 |       1 |       0 |       0 |
|  1 |       2 |       0 |       0 |
|  2 |       0 |       1 |       0 |
|  2 |       0 |       2 |       0 |
|  3 |       0 |       0 |       1 |
|  3 |       0 |       0 |       2 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+
```

I'm sure I could do this with some numpy style manipulation, but I am trying to get a better grasp on pandas, and would like to do it in a pandas-y way.

My naive guess would be to use something with `groupby`, but I am not sure how I would generate multiple columns from that. Something along the lines of

```
data.groupby('id').agg({'value': something})
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [get_dummies()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) and multiply it by `value` column:

```
In [58]: df[['id']] \
           .join(pd.get_dummies(df['id']).mul(df['value'], axis=0).add_prefix('value_'))
Out[58]:
   id  value_1  value_2  value_3
0   1        1        0        0
1   1        2        0        0
2   2        0        1        0
3   2        0        2        0
4   3        0        0        1
5   3        0        0        2
```

Explanation:

```
In [53]: pd.get_dummies(df['id'])
Out[53]:
   1  2  3
0  1  0  0
1  1  0  0
2  0  1  0
3  0  1  0
4  0  0  1
5  0  0  1


In [52]: pd.get_dummies(df['id']).mul(df['value'], axis=0)
Out[52]:
   1  2  3
0  1  0  0
1  2  0  0
2  0  1  0
3  0  2  0
4  0  0  1
5  0  0  2
```

Comment: Ah yes, this is great. My idea in numpy was the same, but I wasn't aware of the `mul` method. Thank you very much!